# Tensorflow won't import using Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to get Gpt-2 to work on Win10 intel i7 950 and have set up an env in Anaconda (Python 3.5, Tensorflow 1.12) but I am not even getting past the import of tensor flow. I have read several questions regarding similar problems but none of the fixes/workarounds have worked for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Here is my Anaconda env:

```
# packages in environment at D:\anaconda3\envs\gpt-2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1
chardet                   3.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
fire                      0.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.30.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.8                      pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       20.1.1                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.5.6                he025d50_0
regex                     2017.04.05               pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                40.2.0                   py35_0
six                       1.10.0           py35h06cf344_1
tensorboard               1.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.31.1                   pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.24.3                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_0
wincertstore              0.2              py35hfebbdb8_0
zipp                      1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I have tried up/down-grading packages but from my understanding, Gpt-2 will not work with higher versions of Python and TensorFlow.

*edit
I tried the "conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu" which installs a full tensorflow environment, I also tried downgrading to tensorflow 1.5, both work but none of them works with gpt-2

*edit 2
I looked at the code that generates the error message and it is not a dll that is being loaded despite what the message says. It is a .pyd file: "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd"

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do a pip install, sometimes this DLL error may appear while trying to import tensorflow. Go to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip then click on Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 as given in screenshot.
[image]

Now download and install the required executable 64 bit or 32 bit. This resolved my issue. Please try this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I installed the vc_redist.x64.exe using the link you gave me. Completed without errors. Restarted the Anaconda powershell and tried import tensorflow as tf, but it gave the exact same error message. Do I have to add it to the environment in some way too?

Comment: `conda create -n envname`
`conda activate envname`
Now inside that env do the following:
`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`
installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (Restart your system after this.)
Checked importing tensorflow and it worked.

Comment: I can get it to work if I upgrade to tensorflow 2.2 like you suggest but that does not help me since gpt-2 need 1.12-1.13.2. I looked at the source code now and the module that will not load is lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd